# Mysql database adding data query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am building a LAMP system. My database will have at least 1 Million rows.

My query is:-

Each individual row in the database will have like 8-10 categories. Each type of category will have a predefined number. For example - 1 = India, 2 = USA, 3 = UK,etc

So will it be add these individual categories in each row in different row of MYSQL  or will it be better to put all the concerned categories for an individual row in one MYSQL row separated by commas.

Which of the above system is more efficient storage wise and processing wise.

Thanks

Vishal ved

Comment: you should read about database first, you will get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

you may use an other table for handling category types (enumeration) and create a foreign key
which you can pass it your row
this will decrease overall insertion size and improve your overall efficiency.
also add index to the category id field. 1 million is not a count for a properly indexed table

Comment: Lets say I have 100 total different types of categories. I will put all the 100 types of categories in on table with a primary key.This primary key will be foreign key in my main table. If for each row in my main table there are 4 categories, then will I have 4 rows in main table with different categories (foreign key from categories table).So if I have around 1 Million rows in NY database, so I will have around 1 Million* 4 = 4 Million rows.Will Mysql be able to handle so much data. Please guide me.

Comment: The answer is really simple, rather putting each category against each row in your main table. Save all 4 ids as a string with a delimiter lets say (,). You can use implode and explode functions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Will using commas as delimiter(which is also my most favored way) be fast performance wise. Will this technique with comma separator not slow the database search since there are going to be around 1 Million rows.